# firebase snapshot value to dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my app there is a data object named room that consists of the following properties...

```
class Room: NSObject {

    var rid: String?
    var owner: String?
    var groupChatName: String?
    var groupChatDescription: String?
    var members: AnyObject?

}
```

Here is the corresponding JSON

```
"A632CA68-40D9-4F3A-B8C8-245457057443" : {
  "groupChatDescription" : "Test Description",
  "groupChatName" : "Test Name",
  "members" : {
    "WuqCAt4mM3h0P0X1m7hVZ7NQyLC2" : {
      "username" : "Steve"
    }
  },
  "owner" : "Steve"
},
```

When I retrieve these values from my database, I put them in a dictionary

```
func fetchAllRooms(){
    Database.database().reference().child("rooms").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let room = Room()

            room.rid = snapshot.key
            room.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

            self.rooms.append(room)

            print("\(room.members)")

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }

        print("end of room snap")

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

The data matches up correctly however handling the members is proving more difficult than I originally expected.

`print("\(room.members)")` Returns

```
Optional({
    WuqCAt4mM3h0P0X1m7hVZ7NQyLC2 =     {
        username = "Steve";
    };
})
```

That is a lot of extraneous text. Especially considering that this is only one member and I need to return a list of members in app.

What I believe would be best for my case is to create a dictionary for the members within the current dictionary. considering each member will have additional attributes such as a reference to their profile image.

So I could call something like `print("\(room.members.usernames)")` and get all the usernames and still be able to use the other attributes later on.

But I don't know if this is the best solution or even where to begin. I was hoping FireBase would have some built in methods to handle this but so far I haven't been able to find anything.

Any answers, suggestions, and or references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly result are you looking for ? is it like getting all result at one Api hit and then reload ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Return a room object with all it's attributes. One attribute is members which should be an array of users.

Comment: Like Returning a array from class room you had used which will be having all the Usernames ? Do you want to get the data in backend ?

Comment: @iOSGeek To be honest I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Guess I'm a bit tired haha. I should be able to create a second database query that gets that information, however I sincerely thought that there might be a more efficient way of doing it. Maybe not. I'm going to do what you recommended by getting the data in the backend for now.

Comment: make use of less queries as possible because to slow down the execution time and load on the Server. just get the all details in one Api hit mechanism and further sort that dictionary as per your requirement and the other method make a function in Object class which will get the details in backend of your code

Comment: Not sure if this is the question but to return all members you can do `room.members.forEach { print($0["username"] ?? "undefined") }`